# not understanding scipy.mgrid[1:6:4j], what is the j means here?

Tags: python, scipy

I can't understand the following code. How is the stepping parameter calculated here? What is the `j` for? And isn't it a complex number?

```
import scipy
scipy.mgrid[1:6:4j]
```

Comment: did you read the docstring? it explains what happens if the step is a complex number.

Answer (score 5):

`scipy.mgrid[1:6:4j]` constructs a list of length `4` where the first element is `1`, the last element is `6` and the step is calculated appropriately (as `(last-first)/(n-1)`)

```
>>> help(scipy.mgrid)
```

> ... if the step length is a **complex number** (e.g. 5j), then the
>   integer part of its magnitude is interpreted as specifying the
>   number of points to create between the start and stop values, where
>   the stop value **is inclusive**.

The documentation is a little misleading. If we read it literally, then `scipy.mgrid[1:6:4j]` should create 4 values (2, 3, 4, 5) between 1 and 6 and the result being `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]` ).

Comment: This is expanded with `np.linspace(1,6,4)` where as `[1:6:4]` would use `np.arange(1,6,4)`.